# Write an expression that looks for a given integer if its third digit (right to left) is 7

Tags: c#

The question is clear however the code is ambiguous . can anyone explain how this code work specifically this segment int thirdDigit = (number / 100) % 10;

```
 using System;

class ThirdDigit
{
static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
    int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int thirdDigit = (number / 100) % 10;  
    if (thirdDigit == 7)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The third digits IS seven!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The third digit IS NOT seven.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand? What `/` does? What `%` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think about the operations applied with a concrete example, 8821 and 7740.

```
8821 / 100 == 88 // integer division
88 % 10 == 8     // and is not 7

7740 / 100 == 77  // integer division 
77 % 10 == 7     // and is 7
```

On the modulo step, the result is only `== 7` if the remainder is 7.

Conceptually it's simpler to think of this as:

1. Strip the one's and ten's places
2. then strip all but the one's place
3. Test the result

Comment: thanks. it is very clear answer

Answer (score 0):

First integer division is used (number/100), this returns a number with the third digit of the original number as its last digit. 12345/100 = 123. Secondly the modulus operator is used (% 10) this returns the reminder when dividing with ten, 123 % 10 = 3.